# Authorize with Firebase Rules API

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-api, google-oauth, api-key

I am trying to access the [Firebase Rules API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#search/firebaserules/firebaserules/v1/) using the  [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis).

I tried OAuth2 and using an API key both obtained through the gcloud console for my project, but both methods got me: ***Error: The caller does not have permission***

This is how i tried to do it with an API key: https://gist.github.com/dergoegge/1e9cbf980148ef3febecaf0eeeb0e1fa

Are there any special restrictions on that api or am i doing something wrong?

Edit: I also tried using service account credentials https://gist.github.com/dergoegge/665d235819429d74c9d448226ec1eba3
and got

```
errors:
   [ { message: 'Invalid Credentials',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'authError',
       location: 'Authorization',
       locationType: 'header' } ]
```

in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the documentation more before asking.

I did not follow all the steps listed here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client

After that it works.

Comment: It may be interesting for future readers to explain in more detail how you did, for the access token but also for the call itself (which syntax).